# Silverlight DB Application available via LocalHost but not Local IP

Tags: database, silverlight, localhost

I am having an issue after I publish a Silverlight App to IIS (everything on my local machine).  The sample app is one page -- a DataGrid populated by Customers from the NORTHWIND DB.

In IIS, if I press the Browse *;50100 button -- localhost:50100 comes up in the Browser and data is displayed in the Datagrid -- all is well!  If I use the address 127.0.0.1:50100 or my local address of 10.10.1.50:50100, I get no data.  All I get is the grid.

SQL Server DB and the App is setup for SQL Authentication (user/pwd).

I have searched everywhere on the NET with no luck -- most posts talk about firewall and DNS, etc.  This is probably neither, because I am not leaving my local box.
Any help -- please....

Comment: Talk about how you accessing this data? WCF? Show the code and configuration. With what you have so far, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I have the exact same issue -- still trying to find out the problem myself.